# How to link against PIC version of a library's dependency in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, fpic

**CMake:**

We have a dependency on [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/).

We build it from source as part of our build system.

**`cpp-netlib/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_library(cpp-netlib
    STATIC
    ${SRCS})
```

For one particular use case, we have to use it in a shared library, so I've created a second library with `-fPIC` enabled:

```
add_library(cpp-netlib_pic
    STATIC
    ${SRCS})
set_property(TARGET cpp-netlib_pic PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE)
```

In my shared library target, I then link against `libcpp-netlib_pic.a`

**`foo/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_library(foo
    SHARED
    ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(foo cpp-netlib_pic)
```

I'm getting a linker error back because `cpp-netlib` is trying to link against the non-pic version of `boost_network`

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../third_party/cpp-netlib/libcpp-netlib_pic.a(client.cpp.o): \
    relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_ZTVN5boost7network4http4impl15normal_delegateE' \
    can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Demangled name:

```
$ c++filt _ZTVN5boost7network4http4impl15normal_delegateE
vtable for boost::network::http::impl::normal_delegate
```

---

**Boost Build:**

This is all part of migrating our existing build system from boost-build to CMake.

The boost-build Jamfiles work fine.

**`Jamroot`:**

```
variant pic : release : <cxxflags>-fPIC ;
```

**`cpp-netlib/Jamfile`:**

```
lib cpp-netlib 
: [ glob src/*.cpp ]
;
```

**`foo/Jamfile`:**

```
shared-lib foo
: [ glob *.cpp ]
  /ext/cpp-netlib//cpp-netlib/<variant>pic
: <link>shared
  <cxxflags>-fPIC
;
```

This works.

Note there is no mention of `boost::network` anywhere, although there is a subfolder in `cpp-netlib/boost/library`, but it contains headers only.

---

**Question:**

How do I tell CMake that `cpp-netlib_pic` needs to use the pic version of `boost_network`?

Comment: Have you tried building boost with the PIC flag (`bjam cxxflags=-fPIC`)?

Comment: Do you have both pic and non-pic versions of `boost_network`?

Comment: @RustyX the boost libraries are present and working. I've updated the question to show that the same source compiles fine using `boost-build`, so this is an issue with configuring CMake, not missing correct build versions.

Comment: @Leon I've updated the question to show that the same source compiles fine using `boost-build`, which I guess shows this is an issue with configuring CMake, rather than with missing the correct build of `boost_network`.

Comment: @RustyX I've proven that the problem is that `cpp-netlib_pic` is not being built with `-fPIC`. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195955/how-to-configure-cmake-to-build-a-library-with-fpic) for further details

Comment: @Leon I've proven that the problem is that `cpp-netlib_pic` is not being built with `-fPIC`. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195955/how-to-configure-cmake-to-build-a-library-with-fpic) for further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a case of not using the correct syntax

Instead of specifying the property:

```
set_property(TARGET cpp-netlib_pic PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE)
```

You have to turn it **`ON`**:

```
set_property(TARGET cpp-netlib_pic PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```