# How to configure CMake to build a library with -fPIC?

Tags: c++, cmake, fpic

I'm trying to create a static library with `-fPIC` specified.

```
add_library(cpp-netlib_pic
    STATIC
    ${SRCS})
set_property(TARGET cpp-netlib_pic PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE)
```

This doesn't work.

The library (`cpp-netlib_pic`) is built without the `-fPIC` flags.

Other targets which link against `cpp-netlib_pic` 
**do** however, have `-fPIC` added to their compiler flags, but the linking fails because `cpp-netlib_pic` didn't.

Here `foo` will have `-fPIC` added:

```
add_library(foo
    SHARED
    ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(foo cpp-netlib_pic)
```

I've proved this to myself with make VERBOSE=1

```
[ 87%] Building CXX object third_party/cpp-netlib/CMakeFiles/cpp-netlib_pic.dir/src/server_request_parsers_impl.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   ... -std=c++14 -Werror -Wall -Wextra ... \
    -o CMakeFiles/cpp-netlib_pic.dir/src/server_request_parsers_impl.cpp.o \
    -c .../third_party/cpp-netlib/src/server_request_parsers_impl.cpp
```

Note no `-fPIC` here.

When building target `foo` which uses `cpp-netlib_pic`, `-fPIC` appears:

```
[ 93%] Building CXX object foo.cc.o
/usr/bin/c++  ... -std=c++14 -Werror -Wall -Wextra ... -fPIC ... \
    -o CMakeFiles/foo_shared_lib.dir/foo.cc.o \
    -c .../foo/foo.cc
```

How can I configure CMake to build the 1st library (`cpp-netlib_pic`) with `-fPIC`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten the `ON`:

```
set_property(TARGET cpp-netlib_pic PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```